# Easy string algorithm not working

Tags: python, string, loops

I am trying to detect values in a string and create a new one based on it. I made a simple model to show you my code. The question is why it is crashing as soon as I run it?

```
objekt = raw_input("Write a binary string: ")

nyfil = ""


count = 0

print objekt[count:2]

while count != len(objekt):
    if objekt[count:2] == "00":
        nyfil = nyfil + "0"
    elif objekt[count:2] == "11":
        nyfil += "1"
    elif objekt[count:2] == "01":
        nyfil += "L"
    elif objekt[count:2] == "10":
        nyfil += "C"
    else:
        pass
    count += 2

print nyfil
```

Comment: what means crashing? what is the error? we don't have to guess it

Answer (score 2):

You are increasing `count` by 2 but have a `!=` comparison in the `while` loop (rather than a `<`).  So if `objekt` has uneven length, you'll be running the loop forever (e.g., `len(object)` is 3, but count only takes values 0, 2, 4, ...).

Answer (score 1):

```
objekt[count:2]
```

This, with an increasing `count`, won’t work as you expect it to. See this:

```
>>> s = '0123456789'
>>> s[0:2]
'01'
>>> s[1:2]
'1'
>>> s[2:2]
''
>>> s[3:2]
''
>>> s[2:4]
'23'
>>> s[4:6]
'45'
```

Furthermore, you should be careful with loop conditions like `count != len(objekt)`. If the length of `objekt` is uneven, you won’t ever get out of the loop at all when you increment `count` by two. Of course, you expect the user to enter an even string, but it’s not unlikely that this won’t happen. A safer condition would be `count < len(objekt)`.

So, your while loop could look like this:

```
while count < len(objekt):
    if objekt[count:count+2] == "00":
        nyfil = nyfil + "0"
    elif objekt[count:count+2] == "11":
        nyfil += "1"
    elif objekt[count:count+2] == "01":
        nyfil += "L"
    elif objekt[count:count+2] == "10":
        nyfil += "C"
    else:
        pass
    count += 2
```

Now to simplify that a bit, you could store `objekt[count:count+2]` in a separate variable, so you won’t have to compute that with every check. You can also get rid of the `else: pass` part because that literally does nothing:

```
while count < len(objekt):
    part = objekt[count:count+2]
    if part == "00":
        nyfil = nyfil + "0"
    elif part == "11":
        nyfil += "1"
    elif part == "01":
        nyfil += "L"
    elif part == "10":
        nyfil += "C"
    count += 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you have is that you are trying to step through the list by 2s, but your count is not incrementing correctly.

To step a list by twos, you can use this:

```
>>> i = '12345678'
>>> for pairs in zip(i[0::2], i[1::2]):
...     print pairs
...
('1', '2')
('3', '4')
('5', '6')
('7', '8')
```

This version uses that loop, along with a lookup dictionary to build your resulting string:

```
d = {'00': '0', '11': '1', '01': 'L', '10': 'C'}

i = raw_input('Enter your string: ')
print ''.join(d.get(''.join(k), ''.join(k)) for k in zip(i[0::2], i[1::2]))
```